# How to fix this Eigen matrix inversion overflow error?

Tags: c++, eigen3

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main() {

    Matrix <float, 2, 2 > J;
    J << 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f;

    Matrix <float, 2, 2 > I;
    I << 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f;

    Matrix <float, 2, 2 > A;
    A = 20.0f * I + 30.0f * J;

    Matrix <float, 2, 2 > B;

    B = 10.0f * I + 25.0f * J;

    Matrix <float, 2, 2 > C;
    C = B;
    cout << C.inverse() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It gives an error which i couldn't fix. I don't know what is meant by "unsolved externals" here and if it is an overflow error how to fix it??

Comment: Someone mentioned that `#include "Eigen/Core"` should be replaced by `#include "Eigen/Dense"`, which seems correct. Then the comment was deleted... I cannot compile whithout this modification.

Comment: @Damien Compilation should work fine, the error will occur during link-time.

Comment: @chtz In practice I got a warning at compilation time ("...inverse ... never defined ..."), this warning becoming an error durink link-time. I was unclear indeed. For these short programs, I perform both compilation and link with the same command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of `MatrixBase::inverse`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a7712eb69e8ea3c8f7b8da1c44dbdeebf) you'll see that it requires you to include `Eigen/LU`. 
Godbolt Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/ydfALn

If you just include `Eigen/Core`, you only get a forward-declaration of `inverse`, the compiler will assume it will be implemented elsewhere and the linker will fail, because it can't find the symbol.

Including `Eigen/Dense` would work as well, since that includes i.a. the `Eigen/LU` header.